# How to add wsse:Security header

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am trying to call a web service in a .net client.  The web service requires the wsse:Security header.  I've added the service reference, how do I go about adding the header?  I'm doing this in c#, .net 3.5

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to do this? I'm working with WSE3.0 from Microsoft, but it's configuration settings are a huge mess, and I'm unable to get anything done.

Comment: Nope.  in our case the vendor eliminated the wss security requirement.  I'd still like to know how to do it though...

Comment: Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734355/clueless-about-how-to-create-soap-wssesecurity-header

Answer (score 0):

That is a ws-security header.
Since you have .net 3.5, you can use WCF, so you should be able to do this in the endpoint configuration.

But what part of ws-security did you want to do? [WS-Security on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)

So I need some more info before I can give a better answer.