# Error when trying to generate service reference from wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

i got a folder with a WSDL file (and all the xsd files related to it) but i can't seem to generate a web service from it using the **"Add service reference"** option in VS2013 (also tried in 2008 just to test). I'm using .net 4.0.

i get multiple error such as:

```
Custom tool error: The global type ('WarningType') has been defined in both
'file:///D:/WSDL/AMA/2011Y/chameleon/AMA_CommonTypes.xsd' and 
'file:///D:/WSDL/IATA/2010.1/chameleon/IATA_CommonTypes.xsd'. 
They are different at './simpleContent/extension/@base'.
```

so, i was advised to use **"Add Web reference"** tool.

this works for some reason. i get no errors now.

**But**, the problem is that i found out that a web reference do not support WS-Security /WS-Adressing
(someone wrote this as a comment in [how to add SOAP Security header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111773/how-to-add-soap-security-header)) and i MUST specify in the header those elements. 
Also, i keep reading not to use a web reference since this is an old technology.

So, does anyone know how to solve the errors I'm getting ?

Comment: Well the error you show looks genuine - I assume you have confirmed that WarningType has indeed been defined in both XSD files?  Probably worth trying to work out why that error is occurring.

Comment: In particular, find out which XML namespace `WarningType` is defined in in the two XSD files.

Comment: You can also use Sopa Ui to generate service proxy objects in sample ways .http://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple tools that generate service proxy objects. Apart from using **Add Service Reference** you can use command line tool **svcutil.exe** which is included as part of the visual studios installation for generating service objects.

Here is how to do this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623148.aspx

This alternative command line approach will help you resolve issue related to WS-Security / WS-Adressing.