# Consuming a wsse java spring security web service with C#

Tags: c#, spring, soap, header, wsse

So in summary I’m trying to consume a javaspring wsse web service using C#. This is what the webservice header I need to send looks like..

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-27777511"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password
 type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
 password</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have tried using wse3.0 custom policy assertions with no luck. I’m using VS 2008. I’m using a basic console application which should pose no problems when consuming this webservice.This is my app.config which is automatically updated when adding the service reference

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsSoap11" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My client code to call the service is:

```
            SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
            HttpTransportBindingElement transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

            CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://11.11.22.222:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/studyEventDefinition/v1/studyEventDefinitionWsdl.wsdl");

            ServiceReference1.wsClient cl = new  wsClient(customBinding, endpoint);

            cl.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "x";
            cl.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "y";

            studyRefType sr = new studyRefType();
            sr.identifier = "S_12345";

            listAllRequest la = new listAllRequest();
            la.studyEventDefinitionListAll = new studyEventDefinitionListAllType();
            la.studyEventDefinitionListAll.studyRef = sr;
            var response = cl.listAll(la);
```

I got the custom binding example from here [Creating Headers (wsse) Section of WCF Client Programatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247536/creating-headers-wsse-section-of-wcf-client-programatically-in-c-sharp). The endpoint is http and I cannot send timestamp hence is used it.

I get an error:

> The 'CustomBinding'.'http://tempuri.org/' binding for the
>   'ws'.'http://openclinica.org/ws/studyEventDefinition/v1' contract is
>   configured with an authentication mode that requires transport level
>   integrity and confidentiality. However the transport cannot provide
>   integrity and confidentiality.

I’m sorry if I’m blunt in anyway. This is my first attempt trying to consume any java spring webservice. I can provide more information if needed. I would prefer to do it programatically in my .cs file. Thank you so much for any thoughts/help.