# How to get to WSHttpBinding's Security property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wcf-security, .net-4.5, ws-security

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.security.aspx, .NET Framework 4.5's  `WSHttpBinding` class has a public `Security` attribute of type `System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity`.

The problem is `WSHttpBinding` is missing this attribute. If I inspect an object of that type with the debugger, it shows no such property:

[image: Debug inspector showing no Security property]

Also, Intellisense shows no `Security` property:

[image]

**IMPORTANT**: Notice that I am setting the `Security` attribute using the object initializer! And Visual Stuido is fine with that!?

In [Correct way communicate WSSE Usernametoken for SOAP webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836685/correct-way-communicate-wsse-usernametoken-for-soap-webservice), @Chris Marisic shows where he modifies this object.

This app is being compiled for .NET Framework 4.5.

What gives?

Comment: What type is `service.Endpoint.Binding`?  It's probably a super-type of `WSHttpBinding`, so it's showing only relevant properties for its actual defined type. **Edit**: [ClientBase.Endpoint.Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.binding.aspx) is type [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.aspx), so you're only seeing the properties relevant to that type.

Comment: It is a generic type of `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding` per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpoint.binding.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpoint.binding.aspx) property of `ClientBase.Endpoint` is of type [`System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.aspx), which is a generic abstract class that is the parent type of all Binding types.  So you are seeing the intellisense for that type.

You need to set the properties on the actual `WSHttpBinding` instance before you assign it, as you are doing now with the object initialization syntax.  Another method would be to assign it to a local variable first:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode....);
binding.Security = new WSHttpSecurity();
// etc.
service.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
```