# consume ws-security java service from .net 4 WCF

Tags: winforms, wcf, .net-4.0, jax-ws

I am trying to consume a JAX-WS web service with basic username/password token in the Soap header.  I've tested that JAX-WS service is working with SoapUI. Now I've moved onto the .net client. The .net client will be a windows forms application. I've added the service reference and set the username and password values. When I execute the web method, there is no security header in the soap xml.  From what I gather in my research I need to set the service client to use message level security. This is where I'm stuck and can't figure out.

Here is my code

```
MyServiceProxy serverService = new MyServiceProxy.MyServiceProxyClient();
MyServiceProxy inputVO = new MyServiceProxy.getAddressFormatInput();
MyServiceProxy outputVO = new MyServiceProxy.getAddressFormatOutput();
//set username and passwrd
serverService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
serverService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD";
inputVO.addressNumber = 13602;
inputVO.addressNumberSpecified = true;
outputVO = serverService.GetAddressFormat(inputVO);
```

It's posting this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:orac="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP550010/">   
<soapenv:Body>
    <orac:GetAddressFormat>         
         <addressNumber>13602</addressNumber>
   </orac:GetAddressFormat>
</soapenv:Body>
```

When I need it to post this (notice the security header)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:orac="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP550010/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:mustUnderstand=">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>   
        <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>  
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <orac:GetAddressFormat>
        <addressNumber>13602</addressNumber>
    </orac:GetAddressFormat>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I get .net to put the security info into the soap header?

Here is the closest I can find to a solution, but I can't find a way to set the security mode.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication

Please help. I appreciate any help in advance.

As requested here is the binding section of my app.conf there is no service section

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyWebServiceProxyPortBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://MyWebServiceProxy"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyWebServiceProxyPortBinding"
            contract="MyWebServiceProxyService.MyWebServiceProxy"
            name="MyWebServiceProxyPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

SOLVED USING THIS LINK

[With C#, WCF SOAP consumer that uses WSSE plain text authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327960/with-c-wcf-soap-consumer-that-uses-wsse-plain-text-authentication/14334760)

in code I did the following

```
var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11,   Encoding.UTF8);
var transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();            
var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

ServiceReference1.MyWebServiceProxyClient client = new     ServiceReference1.MyWebServiceProxyClient();
ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatInput inputVO = new ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatInput();
ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatOutput outputVO = new     ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatOutput();

client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";            
inputVO.addressNumber = 13602;
inputVO.addressNumberSpecified = true;
outputVO = client.GetAddressFormat(inputVO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED USING THIS LINK

[With C#, WCF SOAP consumer that uses WSSE plain text authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327960/with-c-wcf-soap-consumer-that-uses-wsse-plain-text-authentication/14334760)

in code I did the following

```
var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11,   Encoding.UTF8);
var transportElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();            
var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

ServiceReference1.MyWebServiceProxyClient client = new     ServiceReference1.MyWebServiceProxyClient();
ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatInput inputVO = new ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatInput();
ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatOutput outputVO = new     ServiceReference1.getAddressFormatOutput();

client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";            
inputVO.addressNumber = 13602;
inputVO.addressNumberSpecified = true;
outputVO = client.GetAddressFormat(inputVO);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Security` settings are on the binding, which is typically set up in the XML Config file.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx).

To set from code, use the `MyServiceProxyClient(Binding, EndpointAddress)` constructor.

Comment: If you need additional guidance, post the `services` and `bindings` sections.  You should be looking in a file called `App.config` or `Web.config`.  Do not delve into the `Service References` folder, as that is for internal book-keeping for VS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to specify a security setting - the default for `basicHttpBinding` is `None`.  Modify the `<binding>` part of your config file like this:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyWebServiceProxyPortBinding">
          <security mode="Message" clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: nothing I try in the app.config works. closest I can make sense is <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">                  
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default">                    
                  </message>
                </security> but that still doesn't pass the security header....