# C# Runtime Error when implementing WSSE Security Headers with custom fields in SOAP request

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, ws-security, blueprism

I am trying to send a **SOAP request** to a web service that uses **WSSE** and UsernameToken for authentication. The sample query is as follows (masking confidential data):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:kas="http://webservice.com">
        <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>abc</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:CustomField>123</wsse:CustomField>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <kas:method1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <method1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <queryNo>12345678901</queryNo>
         </method1>
      </kas:method1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have generated a proxy class using **WSE 3.0** and the problem is that I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The problematic part of my C# code is below:

```
queryNoSorguType q = new queryNoSorguType();
string query_parameter = query_no;
q.queryNo = query_parameter;

ResultType[] r = new ResultType[10];

UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("abc", "123",PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
//mWebService.SetClientCredential<UsernameToken>(token);
//Policy webServiceClientPolicy = new Policy();
mWebService.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
//mWebService.SetPolicy(webServiceClientPolicy);

//r = mWebService.documentQuerybyQueryNo(q);

System.Data.DataTable outputDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
//System.Data.DataRow outRow = outputDataTable.Rows.Add();
//outRow["field1"] = r;
output = outputDataTable;
```

I located the problematic part by systemically commenting out portions of my code. I am quite unfamiliar with web services, C# and I am actually implementing this in **Blue Prism**. Although this program works with SOAP web services out of the box, unfortunately it does not natively support SOAP headers.

The SOAP request works fine in **SOAP UI** and there are no compiler errors in Blue Prism. I tried adding the headers as instructed in the manual and on the web, but it did not work. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT** 
After writing, compiling a console application in Visual Studio 2017 I get the following error. As far as I understand it does not have the definitions for the headers.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at WebService.queryByQueryNo(queryNoQueryType queryByQueryNo1) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Web References\WebService\Reference.cs:line 1533
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 33
```

Comment: if you are debugging, I suggest inspecting every part of mWebService.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens, if mWebService.RequestSoapContext or mWebService.RequestSoapContext.Security or mWebService.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens is null, your code will fail.

Comment: @ralf.w. Thanks for the comment. Actually after isolating the program and running it through Visual Studio I get different errors. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: @Vesnog you mentioned, that SoapUI request works fine. Could you please provide soap request dumps from SoapUI and from your .net app?

Comment: @Vesnog and corresponding server responses

Comment: do you have any security certificate involved in this process?

Comment: @Vesnog could you see my answer?

Comment: @Pavan No I do not have a certificate involved in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to utilize a different method and quit trying to use a proxy class for the time being as there were problems associated with it. Making use of the answers on this link: [Client to send SOAP request and receive response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response) I came up with my own solution after some customization.

However, I still wonder how to proceed in order to make it work using **wrapper classes**  defined by Visual Studio or WSE 3.0. After writing the code and testing it in Visual Studio it was pretty easy to port it into Blue Prism.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace WebService
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Execute a Soap WebService call
        /// </summary>
        public static string Execute(string queryNo)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:customNAMESPACE=""http://webservice.com"">
                <soapenv:Header>
                    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">
                        <wsse:UsernameToken>
                            <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
                            <wsse:CustomField>CODE</wsse:CustomField>
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                     </wsse:Security>
                  </soapenv:Header>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <customNAMESPACE:QueryByQueryNo>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <QueryByQueryNo>
                            <!--Optional:-->
                            <queryNo>" + queryNo + @"</queryNo>
                        </QueryByQueryNo>
                      </customNAMESPACE:QueryByQueryNo>
                  </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>");

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                    return soapResult;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://webservice.com/webservice?wsdl");
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0 || args.Length > 1)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Please provide a query no");
                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: WebService.exe 3523423333");
                return;
            }

            string output, XMLresponse;
            try
            {
                XMLresponse = Execute(args[0]);
                output = "Successful query";
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.LoadXml(XMLresponse);  // suppose that str string contains the XML data. You may load XML data from a file too.
                XmlNodeList resultCodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("resultCode");
                XmlNodeList resultNoList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("resultNo");
                int i = 0;
                var OutputTable = new DataTable();
                OutputTable.Columns.Add("Result Code", typeof(string));
                OutputTable.Columns.Add("Result No", typeof(string));
                foreach (XmlNode xn in resultCodeList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(resultCodeList[i].InnerText + "  " + resultNoList[i].InnerText);
                    OutputTable.Rows.Add(resultCodeList[i].InnerText, resultNoList[i].InnerText);
                    i++;
                }

            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HTTP POST request failed!");
                output = "!!!HTTP POST request failed!!!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is the xml structure punctually the headers
when you use

`<wsse:Security` wsse is not defined, I know you defined in the same line but why not try put it on the document, something like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:kas="http://webservice.com" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>abc</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:CustomField>123</wsse:CustomField>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: @Vesnog Could you see my answer?

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, the problem is I was trying to send the SOAP request by using wrapper classes generated by Visual Studio. I did not exactly understand your point.